# Was ist ein „verkürztes Partizip“ in der deutschen Grammatik?

Tags: grammar, terminology

Meine Lehrerin hat *worden* ein *verkürztes Partizip* genannt, aber ich verstehe nicht, ob nur *worden* ein *verkürztes Partizip* ist oder ob der Begriff grammatikalisch etwas anderes bedeutet. Was ist ein *verkürztes Partizip*?

Comment: Habe ich so noch nicht gehört, aber ich vermute, es ist das Fehlen der Vorsilbe *ge-* gemeint (_worden_ gegenüber _geworden_). Im Zweifel die Lehrerin fragen, was sie meint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Kontext, in dem die Lehrerin das gesagt hat, fehlt, aber das Partizip *geworden* wird in Passivkonstruktionen mit zusammengesetzten Zeiten zu *worden* verkürzt:

> Ich bin gewarnt **geworden** -> Ich bin gewarnt **worden**.

(siehe z.B. [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Genera/Flexion.html)) Das könnte man ein *verkürztes Partizip* nennen, obwohl es nur bei *werden* auftritt, also keine allgemeinere Anwendung hat.

Comment: Es gibt auch andere verkürzte Partizipien, z.B. "Das habe ich kommen sehen". In früheren und dialektischen Sprachvarianten wird die Silbe *ge-* noch weitaus häufiger weggelassen.

Comment: @KilianFoth: "kommen sehen" ist aber kein verkürztes Partizip, sondern der Ersatzinfinitiv (http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Ersatzinfinitiv-35882), der hier zufällig die gleiche Form hat.